# ¿Como sumar/agrupar 2 filas con LinQ en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, linq

Tengo una consulta/desconocimiento de como realizar un "SELECT" con "SUM" en LinQ. He estado buscando por la web pero no encontré nada que pudiera ayudarme. Este es mi código y una imagen.

```cs
            using (tiendaAntonyEntidades db = new tiendaAntonyEntidades())
            {
                var clientes = from cliente in db.tbCliente
                               join persona in db.tbPersona on cliente.idCliente equals persona.idPersona
                               join credito in db.tbCreditos on cliente.idCliente equals credito.idCliente
                               select new
                               {
                                   DNI = persona.DNIPersona,
                                   NOMBRE = persona.nombrePersona,
                                   APELLIDO = persona.apellidoPersona,
                                   TELEFONO = persona.telefonoPersona,
                                   FECHA_ALTA = cliente.fechaRegistroCliente,
                                   DEUDA = credito.subtotalCredito
                               };
                dtgClientes.DataSource = clientes.ToList();
            }
```

El resultado es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que el la columna "DEUDA" se obtenga la suma total, ya que son el mismo cliente.

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano, gracias!.

Comment: Hola. Has encontrado una solucion a esta problema?

Comment: No, ninguna. Opté por separar la columna deuda y enviarla a otra vista :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio deberia funcionar con el agrupado de la select que tienes

```
        using (tiendaAntonyEntidades db = new tiendaAntonyEntidades())
        {
            var clientes = (from cliente in db.tbCliente
                           join persona in db.tbPersona on cliente.idCliente equals persona.idPersona
                           join credito in db.tbCreditos on cliente.idCliente equals credito.idCliente
                          .GroupBy(s=> new{
                               DNI = persona.DNIPersona,
                               NOMBRE = persona.nombrePersona,
                               APELLIDO = persona.apellidoPersona,
                               TELEFONO = persona.telefonoPersona,
                               FECHA_ALTA = cliente.fechaRegistroCliente,
                           }).Select(p=> new
                           {
                               DNI = p.Key.DNIPersona,
                               NOMBRE = p.Key.nombrePersona,
                               APELLIDO = p.Key.apellidoPersona,
                               TELEFONO = p.Key.telefonoPersona,
                               FECHA_ALTA = p.Key.fechaRegistroCliente,
                               DEUDA = p.Sum()
                           }));
            dtgClientes.DataSource = clientes.ToList();
        }
```

Revisalo a ver si te vale y sino podemos darle una vuelta más